# remove databases with non utf-8 characters in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Good afternoon

How can I remove a database with a non utf-8 character?

See in attach show the database is showed by show dbs command

Thanks for the attention

Regards[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vn3U.png)

Alexandre Bunn

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would do

```
use [db];
db.dropDatabase();
```

What the `use` command actually do is to put the database object to `db`. With UTF-8 database names you may find it impossible to run the `use` command. As an alternative way to get the `db` object, you can run `db.getSisterDB([db name])` then drop it.
So this should do the trick:

```
var db2 = db.getSisterDB(emptyDbs[0].name);
db2.dropDatabase();
```

There's another method `getSiblingDB` which returns the same `db` object. If you are wondering what's the difference between them, well, no difference.

```
replset:PRIMARY> db.getSiblingDB
function (name) {
    return this.getMongo().getDB(name);
}
replset:PRIMARY> db.getSisterDB
function (name) {
    return this.getMongo().getDB(name);
}
```

**EDIT:** 
As the solution above doesn't work for you. I think the last thing you can try is to go to `dbpath`, find the files named by the UTF-8 characters and delete them. You probably won't file any file under that name. Because when you see (empty) follow a db name, it usually means the db is deleted. If so, just restart the instance would fix the problem.
Remember to stop the database before doing this. And do backup before doing anything.

**This way only works for MMAPv1 storage engine.**

Comment: I think the code is pretty straight forward. But ok I add some explanation.

Comment: Good morning

I've tried by this way but it didn't work. Although the dropDatabase() command shows that the database was removed, when I run show dbs it's still there.

> emptyDbs[0].name
�
> emptyDbs[1].name
�
> var db2 = db.getSisterDB(emptyDbs[0].name);
> var db3 = db.getSisterDB(emptyDbs[1].name);
> db2.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "�", "ok" : 1 }
> db3.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "�", "ok" : 1 }
> show dbs
<other databases>
�    (empty)
�    (empty)

Comment: @AlexandreBunn Add some comment for the next thing you can try.

Comment: After restart mongodb the database was removed. Thanks for your helped.